# How to replace a line contain something with that same thing ( LINUX )?

Tags: linux, shell

How to replace a line contain something with that same thing

for example i have line with random thing and contain ( email ) in that line 
and i want to replace all lines with the email that has it in that line for example - all emails will start with ( abuse@.* )

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa abuse@xx.com
-random lines with no email- 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb abuse@sdds.net
-random lines with no email- 
cccccccccccccc abuse@sss.org
-random lines with no email-
```

my output must be

```
email: abuse@xx.com
-random txt with no email- 
email: abuse@sdds.net
-random txt with no email- 
email: abuse@sss.org
-random txt with no email-
```

so it search for line has ( abuse@.* ) for ex. abuse@xx.com
get the email then delete that line and put 
email: abuse@xx.com instead of that line

in shell code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would gsed -i  (or just sed -i on linux) be of use?

```
$ cat substitute.txt 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa abuse@xx.com
-random lines with no email- 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb abuse@sdds.net
-random lines with no email- 
cccccccccccccc abuse@sss.org
-random lines with no email-


$ cat substitute.txt | gsed -s "s/.*\(abuse\)/email: \1/" 
email: abuse@xx.com
-random lines with no email- 
email: abuse@sdds.net
-random lines with no email- 
email: abuse@sss.org
-random lines with no email-

$  gsed -i.bak -s "s/.*\(abuse\)/email: \1/" substitute.txt     
$ cat substitute.txt
email: abuse@xx.com
-random lines with no email- 
email: abuse@sdds.net
-random lines with no email- 
email: abuse@sss.org
-random lines with no email-
```

Comment: worked for me thank you ... but what if i want to keep that line as it is 
but add new line after it with 
( email : abuse@....... )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same, mostly, just **hold** (h), **hold with append** (H), and then **grab** (g):

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-11-161:~/dev$ cat substitute.txt  | sed -s "/\(.*\)\(abuse\)/{ h;s/.*\(abuse\)/email: \1/;H;g;}"
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa abuse@xx.com
email: abuse@xx.com
-random lines with no email- 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb abuse@sdds.net
email: abuse@sdds.net
-random lines with no email- 
cccccccccccccc abuse@sss.org
email: abuse@sss.org
-random lines with no email-
```